# Looping through json and display multiple rows

Tags: jquery, json

I have done very little work with JSON DATA and have been struggling with this for several days now.

a section of my app [using jquery datatables] displays info on the amount of available funds on a service contract. When I drill down i want to see all the modifications to the contract.
and I am using a ajax call to get this data.  I have been successful in displaying a single row of information being returned but not multiple rows.

Here is what I have so far

my JSON DATA - i have not seen a data set like this used in any example any where.

```
{"SUCCESS":true,
 "ERRORS":[],
 "DATA":{
    "COLUMNS":["REQNUM_ID",
               "PORDER_ID",
               "REQNUM",
               "AWARD_DTE",
               "AWARD_AMNT",
               "DTE_ENTERED",
               "ENTERED_BY",
               "DTE_MOD",
               "MOD_BY",
               "VALID_FLAG",
               "MOD_NUM",
               "DESCRIPTION",
               "PROCRGN"],
    "DATA":[
           [2,35,"144-12DG-261","October, 25 2011 00:00:00",2155.02,"March, 28 2012 00:00:00",48317,null,null,"Y",1,null,"DG"],
           [3,35,"144-12DG-264","November, 14 2011 00:00:00",0,"March, 28 2012 00:00:00",48317,null,null,"Y",2,null,"DG"],
           [4,35,"144-12DG-268","December, 09 2011 00:00:00",1000.00,"March, 28 2012 00:00:00",48317,null,null,"Y",3,null,"DG"]
           ]
 }
}
```

My code : the code below actually gives me two rows not 3, but, its the first set of data repeated twice.

```
// the table containing the index data
var oTable_2 = "";
// the select row
var nTargetRow = "";
// 
//var poid = #CntModVal.porder_id#; //should from + column
//
var aData = ""; // holds the text for selected row (column position is critical)
/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------
Jquery Ajax action scrpts
----------------------------------------------------------------------- */
// Method retrieves the selected row index id and executes the ajax call
function getModDetails() 
{   
//alert('getModDetails');

// retrieve the data from the selected row
aData = oTable_2.fnGetData( nTargetRow );
//alert('adata[1]  ' + aData[1]);
  // build the url for the ajax call to use
var cfcUrl = '#application.ajax_url#';
    cfcUrl +='RemoteModDetails.cfc?';
    cfcUrl += 'method=getPos';
    cfcUrl +='&porderid=' + aData[1] ; // contract id


// make the ajax call
$.ajax(
     {
        type: "GET",
        url: cfcUrl,
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (objResponse )
            {   //alert('retrieve the data step 3');
               if(objResponse.SUCCESS)
                {  // alert('success');
                    openModDetailRow(objResponse.DATA);

                }
                else
                {
                    ShowErrors(objResponse.ERRORS);
                }
            },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                ajaxErrorHandler( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown );
            }
    });
}

// Function ajaxErrorHandler
//    DESCRITPION:  Error Handler fir the error message for failed ajax call'
//    PARAMETERS:
//      jqXHR       = The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object,
//      textStatus  = a string describing the type of error that occurred 
//                    and an optional exception object, if one occurred. 
//                    Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are 
//                    "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror". 
//      errorThrown = the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" 
//                    or "Internal Server Error."
function ajaxErrorHandler( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
{
alert('Unable to retieve the requested information due to a server error');
}
// Handle the failed response error
function ShowErrors( statusMsg)
{
alert('Unable to retieve the requested information. Status: ' + statusMsg);
} 
// create the indormation row based on the data retruned by the ajax call
function openModDetailRow(indexInfo)
{
var sOut = '<table align="left" width="95%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="hiddenTbl ui-widget-content">';   
$.each(indexInfo, function(index,data){
/* Assumes only one row returns; additional rows ignored */
var aReqNumID         = indexInfo.DATA [0][0]; //requisition number id  Award amount
var aPorderID         = indexInfo.DATA [0][1]; // purchase order id 
var aRequistionNum    = indexInfo.DATA [0][2]; //  Requisition number description
var aAwardDte         = indexInfo.DATA [0][3]; // award date date entered
var  aAwardAmount     = indexInfo.DATA [0][4]; //  date modifified
var aDteEntered       = indexInfo.DATA [0][5]; //  entered by
var aEnteredBy        = indexInfo.DATA [0][6]; //   modified by 
var aDteMod           = indexInfo.DATA [0][7]; //   mod number
var aModBy            = indexInfo.DATA [0][8]; //   
var aValidFlag        = indexInfo.DATA [0][9]; //  
var aModNum           = indexInfo.DATA [0][10]; //  
var aDescription      = indexInfo.DATA [0][11]; //  valid flag

//alert('pop details step 4 '  + aPorderID +  ' poid');

// create the additonal information table

// row 1
    sOut += '<tr><td><strong>Mod Number:</strong><br> <strong     style="color:##FF0;">&nbsp;' + aModNum + '</strong></td>';
    sOut += '<td><strong>Requsition Numbeer:</strong><br> ' + aRequistionNum + '</td><td><strong> Award Amount:</strong><br> <strong style="color:##FF0;">$' + aAwardAmount.toFixed(2) + '</strong></td></tr>';
    // row 2
    sOut += '<tr><td ><strong>Award Date:</strong><br>' + aAwardDte + ' </td><td ><strong>Description:</strong><br> ' + aDescription + '</td><td> </td></tr>';
});
// end of table
sOut += '</table>';


// display the row
//alert(sOut);

    //alert(index,data);
    oTable_2.fnOpen( nTargetRow, sOut, 'details' );




}
/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Jquery Display scrpt
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */
$(document).ready(function()
{//alert('insert details step 1');
/*
 * Insert a 'details' column to the table
 */
var nCloneTh = document.createElement( 'th' );   // for header
var nCloneThF = document.createElement( 'th' );  // for footer
var nCloneTd = document.createElement( 'td' );   // for body
nCloneTd.innerHTML = '<img src="./images/details_open.png">';
nCloneTd.className = "center";
// add blank header
$('##MVW thead tr').each( function () {
    this.insertBefore( nCloneTh, this.childNodes[0] );
} );
// add blank footer header
$('##MVW tfoot tr').each( function () {
    this.insertBefore( nCloneThF, this.childNodes[0] );
} );
// add icon open/close info rowrow
$('##MVW tbody tr').each( function () {
    this.insertBefore(  nCloneTd.cloneNode( true ), this.childNodes[0] );
} );
// run the jquery data table script
    oTable_2 = $('##MVW');
    oTable_2.dataTable({
        "aoColumnDefs": 
            [ { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] } ],
        "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc']],
        "iDisplayLength": 5,
        "aLengthMenu": [[5,10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [5,10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
        "bJQueryUI": true
        });/* end data table */

/* Add event listener for opening and closing details
 * Note that the indicator for showing which row is open is not controlled by DataTables,
 * rather it is done here
 */
$('##MVW tbody td img').live('click', function () {
    nTargetRow = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    if ( this.src.match('details_close') )
    {   //alert('close row');
        /* This row is already open - close it */
        this.src = "./images/details_open.png";
        oTable_2.fnClose( nTargetRow );
    }
    else
    {
        //alert('open row step 2');
        this.src = "./images/details_close.png";
        getModDetails();
    }
} );

}); 
/* end ready */
```

so I am missing something and cannot figure out what it is.
  if I put the .each() outside the table tags, it breaks the code and i get nothing.

if i wrap it around this:: oTable_2.fnOpen( nTargetRow, sOut, 'details' );

I get a single row

suggestions???

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Why don't you give jQuery Templates a try (if its possible) http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

Comment: A lot of code to read through... Can you make a nice short example?

Comment: Not to be a grinch but you can't loop through JSON. You can loop through a JavaScript Object but not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You have a variety of errors, but the biggest error is that you are using the *each* statement incorrectly.  You are iterating with your each statement, so you get three loops, but inside you're never using the index, or the data from the statement.

Try either of these solutions:

In your each statement you are getting the index in the arguments but never using them.

```
for(var index = 0; index < indexInfo.DATA.DATA.length ; index++) {
    var aReqNumID         = indexInfo.DATA.DATA [index][0]; //requisition number id  Award amount
    var aPorderID         = indexInfo.DATA.DATA [index][1]; // purchase order id 
    var aRequistionNum    = indexInfo.DATA.DATA [index][2]; //  Requisition number description
    ...
```

or

```
$.each(indexInfo.DATA.DATA, function(){
    var aReqNumID         = this[0]; //requisition number id  Award amount
    var aPorderID         = this[1]; // purchase order id 
    var aRequistionNum    = this[2]; //  Requisition number description
    ...
```

In this second statement, the *this* object is the current object in the array.

**EDIT** updated the looping items

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this.  I tried both suggestions and neither worked. using For(......  just broke the page.  using this broke the script... the hidden row did not open.

Comment: @willemMulder Asimplified example would be I want the data in the json data set displayed as a table.  How do I do this? the table would be displayed when an icon is clicked.

Comment: Let me check this out.  I'll create a JSFiddle to verify my results.  You do have an issue with your loops however.

Comment: It works, I just messed up the item you're looping over.  Try this:  http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingsites/SrTeP/5/